# What is the difference between HTTP_HOST and HTTPS_HOST in apache .htaccess files?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rewrite, apache2

I'm editing an `.htaccess` file..

In RewriteCondition for RewriteRules, `HTTPS_HOST` seems to only match urls that are accessed via `https://` protocol (ssl). I saw in docs somewhere that it's a T/F variable that indicates if the url was accessed using the secure protocol.

However, I'm having trouble finding on the docs whether `HTTP_HOST` only matches `http://` protocols, or if it effectively matches `//` relative protocols, meaning it matches *both* `http://` *and* `https://`.

Can someone confirm one way or the other, or point me to a definitive source for this info?

Also, if `HTTP_HOST` matches *both* protocol variants, what is the best way to filter for matches of *only* `http://` protocols ?

Example:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
Rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^\/\.(?!some-url).*$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
</IfModule>
```

In contrast:

```
...
Rewritecond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^\/\.(?!some-url).*$
...
```

Edit: Experimentation shows that `HTTP_HOST` *does* seem to match both protocols, whereas `HTTPS_HOST` only matches when the protocol, or url starts with `https://`.

.

*(Note re: `apache2` tag

TBH, I am not certain what version of apache I am running.  To try finding out, so I could attach the proper tag..

I tried `httpd -v`, `apache -v`, `apache2ctl -S`, `apachectl -S`, `httpd -S`, etc. (It's not a virtualhost question, and I have nginx, which is think is for that (virtual server) anyway, but I tried those last 3 (virtualhost) commands anyway to see if they would enlighten me on my apache version).

Responses to those commands say either that I must first install apache2, or it is an unknown command.

I have an `/etc/apache2` folder, but not an `/usr/local/apache` (hence no `/usr/local/apache/bin/httpd` folder).

)*

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is no such Apache server variable `HTTPS_HOST`, only `HTTP_HOST`. If `HTTPS_HOST` is set on your server then it's specific to your server.

The `HTTP_HOST` server variable contains the value of the `Host` HTTP request header (ie. the *hostname*), this is irrespective of the protocol used (HTTP or HTTPS). As with all variables that start `HTTP_`, they contain the value of the respective HTTP request header.

Maybe you're thinking of the `HTTPS` Apache server variable? This contains the value `on` or `off` depending on whether the request is over HTTPS or not. So, providing you don't have a front-end proxy that manages SSL then it is the `HTTPS` server variable you use to determine whether the request is over HTTP or HTTPS protocol.

Reference:

- [Apache 2.4 - RewriteCond Directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)

> and I have nginx

So, what are you using Nginx for? Is it your application server? Or are you using it as a front end proxy? In which case, `HTTPS` might not be the variable to use after all.

---

**UPDATE:**

> ```
> Rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^\/\.(?!some-url).*$
> RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
> ```

This doesn't really make sense. The *condition* (`RewriteCond` directive) will never be successful (because the `Host` header never contains a slash), so the redirect will *never* occur.

As mentioned above, the `HTTP_HOST` server variable contains the *hostname* only, eg. `example.com` or `www.example.com`. It does not contain the URL-path, as you appear to be assuming here. Your *condition* is trying to match a literal `/.` *not* followed by `some-url` (using a negative lookahead). The *hostname* will never start with (or even contain) a slash, so it fails at the first character.

> I'm trying to modify an htaccess rule that was blocking letsencrypt renewals, .... So there is the primary issue (.well-known was getting a 403)

To make an exception on a specific rule for a specific URL-path, you would do something like the following:

```
Rewritecond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

This excludes (note the `!` prefix) any URL that starts `/.well-known`. The `!` prefix on the *CondPattern* negates the regex. The `REQUEST_URI` server variable contains the full URL-path from the request (which naturally excludes the protocol, hostname and query string).

However, you state that "`.well-known` was getting a 403" - you may need to find out what was triggering the 403 and apply an exception to that rule.

OR, include a single exception at the very top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
# Any requests that start "/.well-known" are ignored
RewriteRule ^\.well-known - [L]
```

(Note the absence of the slash prefix on the `RewriteRule` *pattern* that matches the URL-path.)

> Initially (and maybe secondarily now also) I thought requiring https on an expired certificate might be a problem.

Yes, that will certainly be a problem. The user will get a *browser* warning that the certificate is invalid and the request will never reach your server.

Comment: For example: `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
Rewritecond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^\/\.(?!some-url).*$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
</IfModule>
`  Using `HTTPS_HOST` vs `HTTP_HOST`.  From testing, it seems `HTTP_HOST` matches both protocols, whereas `HTTPS_HOST` only matches `https://` I realize the example is odd, not practical - just showing where one or the other might appear.

Comment: I'm using this in `.htaccess` file.

Comment: And, yeah, that's what I found in the docs, but not what I see in .htaccess files, so it's confusing/unclear. In fact, that's the same doc I was looking at when I reached out!

Comment: TBH server stuff flummoxes me. nginx I think is being used for managing multiple domains on the server. Config stuff I did in nginx files was related to that. Also for http vs https and www vs non-www.

Comment: Specifically  I'm trying to modify an htaccess rule that was blocking letsencrypt renewals, causing an certificate expiration. I think I've got it mostly figured out. Fingers crossed! I require https, but thought I might need an exception if it's expired. So there is the primary issue (.well-known was getting a 403). Initially (and maybe secondarily now also) I thought requiring https on an expired certificate might be a problem.

Comment: Oh gracious, I did not even mention htaccess on my Question! Cannot believe how  unclear the Q is. Sorry!

Comment: updated my question! for clarity.

Comment: "...that's what I found in the docs" - Please state where in the docs you've seen `HTTPS_HOST`. The `.htaccess` rule you've posted doesn't make much sense (it will simply exclude everything) - I've updated my answer.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Interestingly, *using* `HTTPS_HOST` in practice, actually *does* act the same as `HTTPS_HOST`, with rewrite rule matching, *if* the protocol is `https://`.  I see now that it *shouldn't*, because it does not exist.  Thanks for clarifying this point.  I have seen `HTTPS_HOST` on various blog posts, and somewhere along the line incorporated it into my `.htaccess` files, and seemed to work as "expected" (ie the same as HTTP_HOST for domain matching, except that it only matched if HTTPS was on.)  I now have a *much* better understanding of these rules!  Previously upvoted. Checkmarked!

Comment: To avoid guess work, you can easily test what value the `HTTPS_HOST` server variable holds (if anything) on your server. Create a rule like: `RewriteRule ^test$ /?var=%{HTTPS_HOST} [R,L]` at the top of your `.htaccess` file. Request `/test` and what do you see in the redirected URL (in the browsers' address bar) after the `var=`? (Test for a request to HTTP and HTTPS.)